# UILayoutConstraint creates constraints that go offscreen

Tags: ios, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

My tableview cell is three labels and a uistepper but if the text in the first label is too long it just moves all the other views over making the stepper go off screen. Here are my constraints:

```
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[name(>=price@750)]-[price(==60)]-[quantity(==20)]-[stepper]-15-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[name]-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[price]-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[quantity]-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views]];
[self.contentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.stepper
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             relatedBy:0
                                                                toItem:self.quantity
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                            multiplier:1.0f
                                                              constant:0.0f]];
```

my labels creation is:

```
UILabel* label = [UILabel new];
label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[label setMinimumScaleFactor:0.5f];
[self.contentView addSubview:label];
return label;
```

The fontSize is defaulted to 17. if i have the following text then the stepper gets pushed offscreen instead of font shrinking.

```
cell.name.text = @"this is my label";
cell.price.text = @"puddle";
cell.quantity.text = @"ha";
```

id post the picture but i dont have enough reputation points. but basically it just acts like the content view is bigger than the real screen width and it pushes the stepper off the screen.

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add this to my name label.

Comment: [self.name setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow
                                               forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add compression resistance priority to your label. Such as:

[self.name setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];